# Understanding cos(theta) and sine(theta)

Tags: math

Is there any detailed document which describe math functions cos(theta) and sine(theta) with respect to image rotation ?

I am trying to imagine when I  use these functions to calculate location of a shifted point/rect when an object is rotated, but I was unable to visualize it .

Can anybody give me a link/document for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 0):

It's Geometry/Trigonometry...  Theoretically you have (or will) learn about them in Math.  But to put a long story short, you will want to translate your Canvas (or other drawing surface) a distance calculated by the cosine and sine functions.  Hypotenuse * cosine(angle in radians) will give you the horizontal displacement, and Hypotenuse * sine(angle in radians) will give you the vertical displacement.  After you translate, you will then want to rotate your Canvas by the angle.

I'm not sure if reversing the order works the same or not.  I believe if you rotate your Canvas first, then all you have to do is translate horizontally the distance you want.  But I could be wrong on that part (since I have never done it in this order).  Personally, I use the first approach.

If you want to learn more about Sine, Cosine, or Tangent, just google "Trigonometric ratios"..